# Wrapping C class header with JNAerator

Tags: java, c++, jna, jnaerator

I have the following code:

Person.h :

```
class Person {

public:
    Person();
    int getAge();
    void setAge(int newAge);

private 
    int age;
}
```

Person.cpp:

```
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person() {
    age = 0;
}

int Person::getAge() {
    return age;
}

void Person::setAge(int newAge) {
    age = newAge;
}
```

I run the following command:

```
java -jar jnaerator.jar -library Person.h -o . -v -noJar -noComp
```

from the jnaerator folder, i gave an absolute path to the Person.h, and its not working, is there any way to produce JNA code via jnaerator to C class header ?